# lcmm() in R Error: Numerical problem by computing fn value of function is : NaN

Tags: r, nan, longitudinal, mixture-model

My data frame `filtered_gmmdf_long` (long format) has no `NA`. It contains the variables `ID`, `time` (i.e. 0, 3, 8, 15, 25), and `wblv` (continuous, approximately Normal distributed).

### Sample data

```r
library(dplyr)
sample = as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,                      0,3,8,15,25,0,3,8,15,25,0,3,8,15,25,0,3,8,15,25,
                             -0.0924870160,0.0274498752,0.2398900582,
                             0.1422529358,
                             0.1440320863,-0.0869990920,0.1423375351,
                            -0.239953000,-0.2378607918,0.1893095329,
                            0.0470979475,0.0681092844,0.0643890367,
                            -0.1299717236,0.0284062668,0.0249408593,
                            0.2341043359,0.0866213575,0.1003340839,
                            0.2721473565),ncol = 3))|>
  mutate(ID = V1, time = V2, wblv = V3)|>
  select(-starts_with("V"))
```

I am attempting to fit a simple growth model using `lcmm()` from package `{lcmm}` before conducting growth mixture models using the same function. I am able to fit models with hlme() fine but am unable to fit even the basic growth model with lcmm().

### Attempt

```r
# gmm1b<-hlme(wblv~time,subject="ID",var.time="time",random=~1+time,
#            ng=1,data=filtered_gmmdf_long)
###This works properly
# gmm2b<-gridsearch(rep=100,maxiter=10,minit=gmm1,
#                  hlme(wblv~time,subject="ID",random=~1+time,
#                       ng=2,data=filtered_gmmdf_long,mixture=~time))
###This also works properly
> lcmm1<-lcmm::lcmm(wblv~time,random=~time,subject="ID",
+            data=filtered_gmmdf_long,link='linear',ng=1)
```

resulting in the error

> Numerical problem by computing fn
> value of function is : NaN

Originally I tried to do this with my entire dataset (n=3255) but I switched to complete responses only (n=873) after receiving this message. I also verified that all variables are identified as either numeric or categorical (with the exception of `ID`).

Based on I_O's comment,I have also tried the following:

```r
> lcmm1<-gridsearch(rep=100,maxiter=10,minit=gmm1b,
+                   lcmm(wblv~time,random=~time,subject="ID",
+                        data=filtered_gmmdf_long,link='linear',ng=1))
```

> Error in lcmm(wblv ~ time, random = ~time, subject = "ID", data = filtered_gmmdf_long,  :
> The model specified in B should be of class lcmm

```r
> lcmm1<-gridsearch(rep=100,maxiter=10,minit=as.vector(coef(gmm1b)),
+                   lcmm(wblv~time,random=~time,subject="ID",
+                        data=filtered_gmmdf_long,link='linear',ng=1))
```

> Error in minit$conv : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```r
> lcmm1<-lcmm(wblv~time,random=~time,subject="ID",
+             data=filtered_gmmdf_long,B=as.vector(coef(gmm1b)),
+             link='linear',ng=1)
```

> Error in chol.default(varcov) :
> the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite

I also tried rescaling wblv such that there were no negative values. Using wblv_rescale, I was able to run the standard growth model, but received an error when attempting to run a 2-class growth mixture model.

```
lcmm1<-lcmm(wblv_rescale~time,random=~time,subject="ID",
            data=filtered_gmmdf_long,
            link='linear',ng=1)
summary(lcmm1)
###This works properly with wblv_rescale but not wblv
> lcmm2<-lcmm(wblv_rescale~time,subject="ID",random=~time,mixture=~time,
+             data=filtered_gmmdf_long,
+             link='linear',ng=2)
```

> Error in .Contlcmm(fixed = fixed, mixture = mixture, random = random,  :
> Please specify initial values with argument 'B'

Comment: Hi Cassondra, according to https://github.com/CecileProust-Lima/lcmm/issues/126#issuecomment-1235519708 you probably need to fiddle with `lcmm`'s `B` argument ("optional specification for the initial values for the parameters").

Comment: I've reviewed the linked post and attempted to fiddle with B based on it's suggestion; however, I am now receiving different errors. I'm curious, does the outcome variable need to be positive for lcmm to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know too little about the underlying mechanics to help. You might get lucky at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as the challenge seems more related to the statistical background (setting initial params for a mixed model optimization) than its implementation with R specifically.